# How to check if like button has been clicked

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a like button on my site, can I check if the user clicked it in the past? **I dont want the user will login to facebook through my website, I want to check it without asking for permissions from the user**. Is that possible? and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by saving a cookie when your user clicks like button on your page. Facebook has some event callbacks of which you can read more here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

The code looks something like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    if(response) {
        var name = 'UserLikesMyPage'
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = name + '=true' + expires + '; path=/';
    }
}
```

Than you can check if this cookie is already set.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('UserLikesMyPage') >= 0) {
    alert('I already like your page')
};
```

And don't forget to remove the cookie if user unlikes your page. This can be found out by the `edge.remove` event

Comment: This won't help if the user has liked the page before already.

Comment: I know about this but I think there is no other way to check if visitor has used like button before

Comment: If you know, then why do you answer with something that does not fit the question?